# Creating a coordinate system with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I would like to create a coordinate system as in the following picture, or at least similar.

**I would really appreciate guidance.**

[image]

Comment: See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155181/coordinate-system-in-latex-with-tikz).

Comment: A guidance is simple: (i) find TikZ manual, (ii) read the first tutorial (A Picture for Karl’s Students). Otherwise this is question "do-it-for-me" ... so, please show what you try to do so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is quite easy if you follow TikZ manual. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [thick, ->] (0,0) -- (0,7);
  \draw [thick, ->] (0,0) -- (7,0);
  \draw [fill] (0.1, 5) circle [radius=.5pt];
  \draw [fill] (6, 0.1) circle [radius=.5pt];
  \draw [->] (0.1,5) -- (6,0.1);
  \node [above] at (0,7) {$H^{\ast }$ (fiber)};
  \node [right] at (7,0) {$H^{\ast }$ (base)};
  \node [left]  at (0,5) {5};
  \node [below] at (6,0) {6};
  \node [above right] at (0.1,5) {$\pi _{4}S^{3}$};
  \node [above right] at (6,0.1) {$\mathbb{Z}_{2}\cdot l_{3}^{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, I'm not quite sure the meaning of your lines in pencil, therefore I did not draw it in my example. However, you should learn from the code above.

Comment: How would I add a coordinate grid to that, @WayneTsai? I would like it to be grey-ish...less visible than the coordinate axes.

Comment: Try `\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (7,7)`.

Comment: Ah, thank you again! Instead of a circle, do I have the option of using another symbol? For example, is there a way to have an open circle?

Comment: Just use the same command without '[fill]'.

Comment: Fantastic! One more question: do you know if there is a way to make the coordinate axes thicker? @WayneTsai

Comment: Use '[ultra thick]' instead of '[thick]', this is the most basic and simplest way.