# draw 2 lines in one tikzpicture box

Tags: tikz-arrows, graphs

Hi I want to draw this:

[image]

(letters and exact size don't matter)

my code is this but it doesn't work I want to mix these 2 lines here.

```
\subfigure
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[smooth,scale=0.8]
\draw[thick,->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[right] {$y$};
    \draw[blue,thick,domain=0:1.5] plot (\x,{\x}) node[above]
    \draw[blue,thick,domain=-1.5:0] plot (\x,{0}) node[above]
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfigure
```

thanks for your helps.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155181/31034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%smooth,scale=0.8
         > = Straight Barb,
dot/.style = {circle, draw, thick, fill=blue, inner sep=2pt,
              label={[fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\small]60:#1},
              node contents={},}   
                        ]
% axis                        
\draw[->] (-2.0,0) -- (2,0.0) node[below  left] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[below right] {$y$};
%
\draw[very thick]
        (-1.5,0.0) node[dot=A] --
        ( 0.0,0.0) node[dot=B] --
        ( 1.5,1.5) node[dot=C];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @negar, you are welcome!

Comment: could you please help me here?I wil be very thankful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569176/draw-some-graph-in-tikz

Comment: @negar, in @ Alenanno's comment to this your question you have two valuable links, how to draw such (random) function!